# Even after adding "display:table" and "table-layout:fixed", I can't get Firefox to respect the "max-width" property

Tags: html, css, firefox, width, max

I was reading that Firefox and Opera will not respect the max-width property unless you add a “display:table” and “table-layout:fixed” into the containing DIV.  So in my containing DIV I put

```
#loginArea {
    border-radius: 25px;
    font-family: 'russo_oneregular';
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    color: #000000;
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    max-width: 580px;
}
```

However, on Firefox, the DIV is still not expanding to reach the 580 pixel max width — https://jsfiddle.net/4sjxum1k/11/ .  How can I make it do that while still keeping the container centered in the middle of the screen (as well as the search elements in a single row)?

Comment: why don't you use flexbox? it has good support http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your `div` is using absolute positioning, it has no default `width` and will only ever be as big as it needs to be to accommodate its contents, up to your specified `max-width`, or as small as it needs to be to fit the available space. To fix this so that it will always expand to fill the available space, up to your specified `max-width` simply add the `width` property giving it a value of 100% - no need for either of the table properties.

```css
body {
  background-color: grey;
}
#loginArea {
  border-radius: 25px;
  font-family: 'russo_oneregular';
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: #000000;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  width:100%; /* ADD THIS */
  max-width: 580px;
}
#searchForm {
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: orange;
}
.searchField {
  display: table-cell;
  line-height: 40px;
  font-size: 22px;
  margin: 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-appearance: textfield;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-rtl-ordering: logical;
  -webkit-user-select: text;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  word-spacing: normal;
  text-transform: none;
  text-indent: 0px;
  text-shadow: none;
  text-align: start;
}
```

```html
<div id="loginArea">
  <div id="searchForm">
    Search For Results
    <br>
    <div style="vertical-text-align:center;">
      <form id="search-form" action="/races/search" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="get">
        <input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓">
        <input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name" placeholder="First Name" class="searchField" style="width:23%" />
        <input type="text" name="last_name" id="last_name" placeholder="Last Name" class="searchField" style="width:23%">
        <input type="text" name="event" id="event" placeholder="Event" class="searchField" style="width:40%">
        <input alt="Search" type="image" src="http://www.racertracks.com/assets/magnifying-glass-0220f37269f90a370c3bb60229240f2ef2a4e15b335cd42e64563ba65e4f22e4.png" class="search_button" height="40" align="middle">
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```